# Execution Plan behaviour with DateTimeOffset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to determine the best way to query date ranges in SQL Server when dealing with DateTimeoffset fields.

My Query

[image]

I would have thought (if anything) the first query would take slightly more effort as there would need to be an implicit conversion from String to DateTimeOffset.

But the **actual** query plan shows somewhat different story

[image]

and it seems the problem lies in the estimated number of rows?

So - with all things being equal, why does using a datetimeoffset parameter rather than a string incorrectly estimate the number of rows returned, and therefore <strike>take an order of magnitude more resources to execute?</strike> show the query cost as taking 96% of the batch?  Is the Query cost just an estimate even though this is the ***actual*** query plan?

[image]

Statistics are accurate and upto date and I've cleaned the proc cache before running the query

[image]

Comment: But the second does not take an order of magnitude more resources to execute.  They will execute the same.   One just has an incorrect estimated  number or rows.  When you run them I suspect the each return the same answer.

Comment: Are you saying the query cost of the **actual** execution plan only takes into account the _estimated_ values?  (and that is expected behaviour?)

Comment: The estimate query cost does not run the query - It come up in a instant even if the query takes forever.  The plan will be based on actual statistics.  A plan that estimates 10000 row will be higher than a plan the estimates 100 rows even if it is the same exact plan.  When the plan is executed it will have an actual time that does not care about the estimate.

Comment: Sorry Blam, I don't think I explained myself in the last comment well enough.  From the Screenshot above (of the _actual_ execution plan), it says the second query takes 96% of the total effort when running both queries (due to the average density of the stats - thanks Dan).  My subsequent question was,  "Even though the image shows the actual execution plan the value `query cost (relative to the batch)` appears to be calculated using _estimated_ values".  Making this piece of information less reliable when determining where to concentrate efforts for performance improvements...

Comment: I don't know how to be more clear than the second does not take an order of magnitude more resources to execute.  Your inference "therefore take an order of magnitude more resources to execute" is wrong.  That is actual execution plan. Both will execute the exact same way.  The execution time is an estimate.  No kidding an estimate is less valuable than actual - move on.  Same execution plan is same execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the literal, the histogram stats are used because the value is known at compile time.  The value is unknown at compile time with the local variable so the average density statistics are used instead, resulting in different row count estimates.

You could either add the `OPTION RECOMPILE` query hint to "sniff" the run time variable value or use a parameterized query.  These methods will use the histogram for the row count estimates.  The latter will also cache the plan so that subsequent executions will use the same plan regardless of the value as long as the plan remains in cache.

This is general behavior and not specific to the datetimeoffset data type.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that make sense re: the average density.   I initially thought the recompile option _wasn't_ the answer because I was freeing the proc cache between executions which would _force_ a recompile. However, yours was exactly the answer (and it corrected the estimated rowcount), which I found a little strange?    Does this indicate the creation of the execution plan only sniffs the parameter if the recompile option is used, and otherwise uses the average density of stats when creating the plan of a query using a parameter?  (updating stats had no effect on this issue)

Comment: @trubs, you are correct that local variable compile-time values are only sniffed with the RECOMPILE hint.  The local variable behavior is different than true parameters, which are sniffed by default.  Note the RECOMPILE hint doesn't actually flush the cache; it causes the plan to be discarded after execution rather than cached (same net effect, though).

Comment: ah-hah!  That helps explain why (one) solution to parameter sniffing of stored procs is to assign the param to a variable before using it.  (and also highlights the problems with that fix)

Comment: @trubs, yes, I've seen shops standardize on using local variables to avoid sniffing, but that's throwing the baby out with the bathwater, IMHO.  Erland discusses the many considerations that vary by version and patch level in his detailed article: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html.  It's a good read that I recommend.